# Value does not fall within an expected range

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, themes, silverlight-toolkit

I got a silverlight 4 application which has a full MVVM design pattern implementation. Im trying to implement a silverlight toolkit theme.

I got a view I place my code here like this

```
<toolkit:Theme x:Name="theme" DataContext="{StaticResource _frameContainerViewModel}" 
               ThemeUri="{Binding ThemeUri}">
```

some code here

in my ViewModel, I change its ThemeUri property

```
ThemeUri = new Uri("/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BubbleCreme;component/Theme.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

after the code step through in my ThemeUri property error pops **value does not fall within expected range**.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi
I had problem like your but with binding to image source and solved this way:

`public string ThemeUri

{

   get; set;

}

// inside some function

ThemeUri = (new Uri("/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BubbleCreme;component/Theme.xaml", UriKind.Relative)).OriginalString;`

Comment: ThemeUri property is a type of Uri not string, how will you bind it to Theme control? thank you

Comment: Change type of ThemeUri property from Uri to String.

Comment: it works! Thank you. +1vote for your answer. Any explanation why needed to put OriginalString?